# div with added class in JS not triggering a mouseover event over multiple elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener, mouseover

my inner-cursor is a circle that should grow to the size of the outer-cursor with the class of .grow when I set the mouseover event in JS. It doesn't trigger when I hover over specifically only buttons (it doesn't trigger at all).
There are multiple buttons (it is a test calculator) all with the class of 'button'.

```
<div class="inner-cursor">
</div>

<div class="outer-cursor">
</div>

<button class="button" type="button" value="1" id="1">1</button>
<button class="button" type="button" value="2" id="2">2</button>
```

```
.inner-cursor {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #627CE4;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.outer-cursor {
   position: fixed;
   left: 10px;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   border: 1px solid #627CE4;
   border-radius: 50%; 
   pointer-events: none;
   transition: 0.1s;
}

.inner-cursor.grow{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}
```

```
let outerCursor = document.querySelector('.outer-cursor');
let buttons = document.querySelector('.button');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor);

function moveCursor(e){
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;


    innerCursor.style.left = `${x}px`;
    innerCursor.style.top = `${y}px`;

    outerCursor.style.left = `${x}px`;
    outerCursor.style.top = `${y}px`;
}

function growCursor(e){
    buttons.addEventListener('mouseover', function (){
        innerCursor.classList.add('grow');
    });
    buttons.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        innerCursor.classList.remove('grow');
    })
};
```

My attempts included the above (which produced no result) and the following where I tried to make the buttons an array (which actually halts the div from following the cursor's movement anymore):

```
let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('b'));

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    buttons.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            innerCursor.classList.add('grow');
});
buttons.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    innerCursor.classList.remove('grow');
});
});
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: For your forEach, you don't need to get an array from querySelectorAll, just loop through buttons for your for each. BUT you need to give button your event listeners, not buttons. Button in that loop represents each button, buttons represents the results from querySelectorAll

Comment: Also your querySelectorAll would need to mention button not B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error in your js code, it must be `button` and not `buttons` inside the forEach function

```js
// use either one here
let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button'));
// added this innerCursor
let innerCursor = document.querySelector('.inner-cursor');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        innerCursor.classList.add('grow');
    });
    button.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        innerCursor.classList.remove('grow');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you! i've added these changes. for some reason the cursor stops tracking now(happens whenever i add the array); though i'll try to sort that out separately lol

Comment: @breanne1209 make this as the answer, adding a fix for the inner div

Comment: This answer is still invalid and won't work properly.

Comment: @imvain2 and how is this wrong? it works exactly as OP wants

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen, if it works exactly as the OP wants, where in OP's code does he have bold elements to mouseover?

Comment: @imvain2 changed from `b` to `.button`